# Existence of a function with certain properties.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $X=\mathbb R^2-p$, with $p\in \mathbb R^2$, and $Y=S^2$. I must determine if exist i) a set theoretic surjective map, ii) a continuous surjective map, and iii) a covering with degree greater than $1$. Now, point i) is easy: we can cover all $S^2$ but a point $q$ with a open disk in $X$ (these two spaces are homeomorphic); then we send all the other point of $X$ in $q$, and this induces a surjective set theoretic map. Point iii) is easy as well: since there are no injections from $\mathbb Z$ to $\{0\}$, it is impossible for $X$ to cover $Y$.

However, how do I show point ii)? Usually when I must prove the non existence of such a map, I use that continuous functions map connected spaces in connected spaces; but here it isn't useful. Am I missing some fundamental theorem? P.S. This should be an exercise of algebraic topology, but I feel that it just require general notions of topology. Thanks for your help

Comment: Do you mean $S^1$ instead of $S^2$?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe I mean $S^2$, it's clear that there are such maps in the case of $S^1$.

Comment: There are lots of subjective maps.  Did you have any in mind or is the reader to figure that out from your subsequent floundering?

Comment: @WilliamElliot I'm not sure I understood your comment; if there are lots of surjective continuous function from $X$ to $Y$, can you make me an example? Thank you

Comment: for a heuristic description of a continuous function $\mathbb{R}^2-p \to S^2$ you can send all points with norm $\leq 1$ to the south pole, all points with norm $\geq 2$ to the north pole, and then interpolate using polar coordinates.

Comment: Alternatively, choose any open metric disk $D\subset \mathbb{R}^2-p$, and the quotient space $(\mathbb{R}^2-p)/D^c$ is homeomorphic to $S^2$.